# Creating Image path for Image in Storage firebase

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

In my database, I have this kind of information about images. I am able to get that data from the database. But I am unable to make Image path from these values. As the image is stored on Storage.
Can Anyone please point me to the right direction? That, an Image present in Storage's Images/ directory, How can I make its full image path by using the given path in image?
[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question: do you need a download URL for that image?

Comment: I'd recommend watching zero to app (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE) and checking out it's source code (https://gist.github.com/puf/8f67d3376d80ed2d02670d20bfc4ec7d)